# Getting number as parameter to use in SQL expression leads to ExecuteError: ERROR 000358?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, parameters, python-script-tool, error-000358

In my script I am using the Select tool (arcpy.Select_analysis) and in the SQL expression, I want to use a number that I call in as a parameter.  I have trying to script it like:

```
subsize = arcpy.GetParameter(3)

where_clause = '\"AreaSqKm\" > {0}'.format(subsize)

arcpy.Select_analysis(waterbodies, lg_waterbodies, where_clause)
```

In this example I'm entering the parameter as the number 0.0005, as a double.

I've tried tweaking it various ways, but every time I try to run the tool I get:
ExecuteError: ERROR 000358" Invalid expression "AreaSqKm > 0.0005 Failed to execute (Select).

If i hard code that variable in a script as 0.0005 and run it as a stand alone it works fine.  Any ideas on why it won't run in arc?

Comment: Is waterbodies and lg_waterbodies shapefile,arcsde,geodatabase etc. please refer different where_clause for each type..

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the escaping backslash ('\"') since you are using single quotes to enclose the whole string. This should work.

```
where_clause = '"AreaSqKm" > {0}'.format(subsize)
```

Comment: Yeah, I have tried this, I think the problem is the way the parameter is being dealt with. I need it to be treated as a number for the SQL expression to work, and it seems like that's where the problem is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The double quotes indicate your field name and should not be escaped with a backslash. Try this instead:

```
where_clause = '"AreaSqKm" > {0}'.format(subsize)
```

To test that works I created the test code and tool dialog below, and it worked.  I reported a couple of variable values using `arcpy.AddMessage()` to ensure that they were actually set to what I thought they were.  You have not specified where your data is stored.  In my test I used a shapefile.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

subsize = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
arcpy.AddMessage("subsize: {0}".format(subsize))

where_clause = '"AreaSqKm" > {0}'.format(subsize)
arcpy.AddMessage("where_clause: {0}".format(where_clause))

arcpy.Select_analysis("C:/polygeo/test.shp","C:/polygeo/TestSelect.shp",where_clause)
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I have tried this, I think the problem is the way the parameter is being dealt with.  I need it to be treated as a number for the SQL expression to work, and it seems like that's where the problem is. Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit your question to indicate where your data is stored as well as the exact error thrown when this syntax is used, please?

Comment: Ok, so I'm also selecting the workspace using arcpy.GetParameterAsText as setting it to a folder where a shapefile (waterbodies.shp) is stored.  I am trying to select waterbodies larger than a given threshold (0.0005 km^2) in this case.  So I use arcpy.Select_analysis and the SQL expression as shown before.  I then get this error: ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression "AreaSqKm" > 0.0005
Failed to execute (Select).  I need the threshold value to be a modifiable number so I can't hard code it into the script.

Comment: I cannot test at the moment but try GetParameterAsText instead of GetParameter.

Comment: I actually have tried that as well, doesn't seem to solve anything...

Comment: How you are configuring your tool parameter may also come into this. What you are trying to do sounds simple so I just need to get to my laptop to test and describe the process.

Comment: There's no rush, but if you get a chance, I would greatly appreciate it!